# how to count number between certain range of rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, vba

i would like to count number for every 7 rows, data are in one column. i use this formula, but it is not working.

from `B8` to `B14329`, for every 7 rows, count number if it is equal to 3. so i know how many 3 in every 7 rows.

```
=COUNTIFS(B8:B14329, OFFSET($B$7,(ROW()-12)*7,0,7,1),B8:B14329,=3)
```

Thanks a lot!
i want something like this:

```
data  count
3    
2   
3   
1   
3   
3   
1       4
1   
2   
2   
3   
3   
1   
1       2
.....
....
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and easy:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B8:B14329=3)*(MOD(ROW(B8:B14329),7)=1))
```

Just change the `=1` to your needs. To start with row 1 `=1`, 2 `=2` ... 6 `=6`, 7 `=0`. This way, to start count at row 8 it is `=1`

**EDIT**: having your exaple now, you want something completely different... lol.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),7)=0,COUNTIF(A8:A14,3),"")
```

Put this in row 14 and then drag down... change the `=0` as you need it.

Comment: not working , got something like this : 
    2     468
    3     468
    1     468

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do

- Add a new column with the row index (8 to 14239) in your case
- Add Yet another column, with a formula to tell whether the column you just added is a multiple of 7. Put it's value like "TRUE" or "FALSE"

You can use the `MOD` function to check the remainder of the division.

```
= MOD ( Number , Divisor )
```

By now, you should have, aside from the columns you already have, something like:

`8-----FALSE`

`9-----FALSE`

`10-----FALSE`

`11-----FALSE`

`12-----FALSE`

`13-----FALSE`

`14-----TRUE`

`15-----FALSE`

Once you have that, just apply a filter on the "TRUE/FALSE" column, select the "TRUE" values and you will be able to count the number of "3"s on the actual value column, by also using a filter on it.

I hope it helps, and it's easier than a really messy formula.